# Android- dynamic overridePendingTransition duration

Tags: android

I am creating an android launcher and am pretty far into it. I ran into a problem though. I need to allow the users to enter the transition duration from activity to activity from setting. The problem is that since the structure of overridePendingTransition is

overridePendingTransition(int,int);

instead of

overridePendingTransition(Animation,Animation);

which means that well I dont know how to set the animation speed dynamicly. I know how to set duration in the anim xml but that is not changable. here is a clip of what I have

`Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packages[position]);
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in,android.R.anim.out);`

I need to set animation speed dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your own Animation like a regular class (means not in xml) and use it.